# Spring Boot: Postgres Character Varying column returns null

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to map an object of the following class to a Postgres table.

```
class MyClass {
    private BigInteger id;
    private String text;
    //public setters and getters
}
```

I also have a table with 2 columns of type: bigint and character varying.

Then I am using a controller to query the db as shown below:

```
@GetMapping(value="/Resource")
public User getUser(@RequestParam BigInteger id) {
    String sql = "SELECT \"ID\", \"TEXT\" FROM \"Table\" WHERE \"ID\"=" + id;
    List<MyClass> objList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
    BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyClass.class));
}
```

While the id is retrieved correctly, the "text" field of the object is returned as null. Is it a datatype mismatch?

Comment: 1. Please use jdbcTemplate as good as possible/[correct](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate)! (avoiding ["lil bobby"(drop tables)](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables) (but it doesn't fix the problem at hand)

Comment: 2. (to the problem) BeanPropertyRowMapper heavily/only relies on naming! (it must be a top level class, have no-args-constructor) [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html) ... `id` is somewhat of corner case/very short "identifier", but probably you could get more lucky with lower case or at least camel-case (in SELECT statement) ..on the other hand you could rename the java side to upper case, but this would injure (many, java, common) conventions...

Comment: and 3. (best), for these "few fields" - write a custom row mapper! "Please note that this class is designed to provide convenience rather than high performance. For best performance, consider using a custom RowMapper implementation."